# Remove trailing commas after concatenating columns using ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I combined values from multiple columns using ISNULL because some columns have null values but it seems like it has also created tailing commas and I'd like to get rid of them.

```
Country       Score1    Score2    Score3
USA             3         2        5
FRA             2        Null      Null
GER             4         5        Null
```

And I combined the Score columns into one and it has trailing commas.

```
select ISNULL(Score1,null) +','+ISNULL(Score2,'') +','+ISNULL(Score3,'') As Score
from table
```

The resulting table looks like this

```
Country       Score    
USA           3,2,5         
FRA             2,,       
GER            4,5,
```

How do i get rid of these commas? I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from SQL Server 2017 you may use `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SELECT Country, CONCAT_WS(',', Score1, Score2, Score3) AS Score
FROM (VALUES
   ('USA', 3, 2,    5),
   ('FRA', 2, Null, Null),
   ('GER', 4, 5,    Null)
) v (Country,  Score1, Score2, Score3)
```

Result:

```
Country Score
USA     3,2,5
FRA     2
GER     4,5
```

But, if you want to use `ISNULL()`, the following statement is also an option (for all supported versions):

```
SELECT 
   Country, 
   STUFF(
      ISNULL(',' + CONVERT(varchar(1), Score1), '') +
      ISNULL(',' + CONVERT(varchar(1), Score2), '') +
      ISNULL(',' + CONVERT(varchar(1), Score3), ''),
      1, 1, ''
   ) AS Score
FROM (VALUES
   ('USA', 3, 2,    5),
   ('FRA', 2, Null, Null),
   ('GER', 4, 5,    Null)
) v (Country,  Score1, Score2, Score3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me,

```
select 
Country, 
concat_ws(',',Score1,score2,score3) as Score 
from tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another trick that you can use:

```
select replace(rtrim(concat(score1, ' ', score2, ' ', score3)), ' ', ',') as scores
from table
```

This works for the following reasons:

- `concat()` ignores `null` values.
- `rtrim()` removes the trailing spaces.
- the values have no spaces in them.
- the `null` values are all at the end.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7fd28bf0a57b3068e73b38f0a5567ac) is a db<>fiddle.